# A Generalised Diophantine Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I submitted without proof (and verification), the following conjecture:

The Diophantine equation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{L} (x_k)^n = y^n$$

has integer solutions only for $n\le L$.

Fermat’s Last Theorem is the special case of $L=2, n>2$. Another special case $n=L=2$ is that of the Pythagorean Triples.

However, presented with two counterexamples (one more than necessary!) I withdraw the aforesaid conjecture, while noting that it is really interesting that it does apply somewhat specifically to $L=2$ (Fermat's Case!)

So A better question to pose is : Seeing as how it does not hold for $L=3$ and $L=4$ , is $L=2$ the only known case or are there possibly other values of $L$ for which it does hold?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ 95800^4 + 217519^4 + 414560^4 = 422481^4   $$

$$  27^5  + 84^5 + 110^5 + 133^5 = 144^5  $$